# .NET Framework 4.0 with WindowXP IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, frameworks

i have installed .net framework 4.0 into my window XP, but i can't find any asp.net 4.0 version during setting IIS. What is the problem? Thank u in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running this command:

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
```

This should re-register ASP.NET with IIS5.1 on your XP machine. If that doesn't work, follow the Web Platform installation from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263) and re-install it on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem that I previously installed .net framework 4.0 client version in my machine, thanks to Matthew Abbott provided the link with .net framework 4.0 full version.

Comment: FYI - Client Profile contains a subset of the BCL - but specifically doesn't not include ASP.NET, which would be why you couldn't see it as configurable through IIS.